# Grails Spock failed to create object for Mocked class

Tags: grails, spock

I have readCSV() method in Microsoft365Offer, that I have mocked. But due to that I can't create object of Microsoft365Offer class.

```
GroovyMock(Microsoft365Offer, global: true)

            Microsoft365Offer.readCSV(_,_) >> {
                Microsoft365Offer microsoft365Offer =  new Microsoft365Offer(
                        "name"                  : "any thing as product name",
                        "offerURI"              : "4A-FAEA24541538",
                        "resellerPrice"         : 1.6,
                        "fob"                   : 1.41,
                        "includedQuantities"    : 0,
                        "minimumValue"          : 0,
                        "taxesPISD"             : 0,
                        "defaultTaxesISS"       : 0)

                println "=====coming in here========$microsoft365Offer"
                return ["1":microsoft365Offer ]
            }
```

Output =====coming in here========null

How I can resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your stacktrace.

Comment: No stack trash, as output being print null.

Comment: You may be hitting Spock Issues 445 (https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/445).  I'd try mocking in a different way, but don't see enough context about your test to suggest a concrete alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the solution, but a workaround for the problem:

```
Microsoft365Offer microsoft365Offer =  new Microsoft365Offer(
                        "name"                  : "any thing as product name",
                        "offerURI"              : "4A-FAEA24541538",
                        "resellerPrice"         : 1.6,
                        "fob"                   : 1.41,
                        "includedQuantities"    : 0,
                        "minimumValue"          : 0,
                        "taxesPISD"             : 0,
                        "defaultTaxesISS"       : 0)

GroovyMock(Microsoft365Offer, global: true)

Microsoft365Offer.readCSV(_,_) >> {
    println "=====coming in here========$microsoft365Offer"
    return ["1":microsoft365Offer]
}
```